# Gulp watch entire folder & compile saved file

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

What I want to do is watch:

myprojects/less

There are hundreds of Less files in this directory. When a file is saved I'd like to compile the saved file only.

The following watches correctly but compiles ALL of the less files. A bit too much overhead.

```
gulp.task('compileCurrentTheme', function () {
// is there a way to get the filename that is saved and pass it dynamically to gulp.src?
return gulp.src('less/**/*.less') 
.pipe(less())
.pipe(gulp.dest('./css')); 
});


gulp.task('watch', function(){
 gulp.watch(['less/**/*.less' ], ['compileCurrentTheme']); 
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/contra/gulp-cached?  
Watch on its own will probably not suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion @CriticalImpact. Although I didn't go with your suggestion, it got me on the right track.

```
var changed = require('gulp-changed');

gulp.task('compileCurrentTheme', function () {
 return gulp.src('less/**/*.less')
 .pipe(changed('./css', { extension: '.css' })) 
 .pipe(less())
 .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});


gulp.task('watch', function(){
 gulp.watch(['less/**/*.less' ], ['compileCurrentTheme']); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to the answer by @Justin W Hall, if using Gulp 4 the format of the watch function is:

```
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch(['less/**/*.less' ], gulp.series('compileCurrentTheme')); 
});
```